# How to input a value from a drop down list into an SQL statement

Tags: php

I would like to obtain a value that is selected from a drop down box. It has entries from a database using jQuery.

I would then like to add the value from the drop down box into the SQL statement to query.

I tried using a submit button to get it to work but struggled.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my option box:

```
<select id="combobox">
                            <?php
                                echo '<option class="option">Type/Select a room</option>';
                                while ($row = $res->fetchRow()) {
                                    $code = $row['roomcode'];
                                    $titles[] = $row['park'];
                                    echo '<option class="option" name="codedrop">'.$code.'</option>';
```

Here is the SQL statement i am trying to add the data into:

```
$resql = "SELECT * FROM 'ROOMS' WHERE 'roomCode' LIKE '$code%'";
                                    $res1 = mysql_query($resql);
```

Comment: Your select needs a `name` attribute and a closing `</select>` tag. Also, `mysql_query` is deprecated. Please update to mysqli or PDO.

Comment: And if you don't sanitize user data, you end up with the possibility of sql injection. (e.g. Bobby Tables problem)

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

0) Add form tags around your select with the attribute `method="post"`

1) Set a `name` attribute for the `select` element

2) Set a `value` attribute for each `option` field

Example  code:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <select id="combobox" name="combobox">
      <option class="option" name="codedrop" value="' . $code . '"></option>
      <option class="option" name="codedrop" value="' . $code . '"></option>
      <option class="option" name="codedrop" value="' . $code . '"></option>
    </select>
</form>
```

**PHP**

Accessing the value of the chosen option in PHP once the user has submitted the form:

```
<?php    $_POST['nameOfSelectElement']; ?>
```